# error on my feedback form code

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill the form again.";
        }
    else{        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\ nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("youremail@yoursite.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

there seems to be some error in the last nested else loop. When I run this code the text is being displayed as is.
the form is being created, but the last part of the else loop is not running.
attached here in is the image of how the output is looking.
please help.
image is at http://s24.postimg.org/s8pc8qznp/Error.png

Comment: `\r\ n` should be `\r\n` (no space)

Comment: Make sure your file is `.php` extension. You do have a problem with the `From:` etc. as Bart said, but besides that, your code works.

Comment: @BartHaalstra That is indeed a problem but doesn't explain why it's showing "code", as per OP's image. It won't hinder sending mail though, just a badly formed From.

Comment: I am using this as a part of a html code, so will I have to save the whole page as HTML or will I have to do this separately?

Comment: yes @Fred, i've tried removing the space in    ` \r\n`    but there seems to be no change in the output behavior.

Comment: Is your file with `.php` extension? If not, it has to be.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm very new to this subject and just a beginner. Can I not use the whole code above as a part of one of my html pages? do I have to save it separately, or do I have to save that whole page as a PHP itself?

Comment: I've tried renaming the page as .PHP file as well, but the code still shows up. What can I do?